# Information between several data in React Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an React app with an Administration zone where the Admin user can add some items in a big catalogue. The data is save in Firebase in "catalogue".

When a simple user of the app connect to her account, he can view the list of the item add by the Admin, and choose to add item in her collection (like add to favorite function). Her collection is then show in private page "user collection".

My problem is when Admin delete item in Admin zone, this item is delete to catalogue too, but not in the user collection.

You can see my code here:

Data from Firebase to "catalogue page":

```
class Catalogue extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {
   catalogue: {}
  };
}

//Item from  Firebase
  componentDidMount() {
  database.on('value', snapshot => {
  this.setState({
     catalogue: snapshot.val()
    });
   });
  }

// Add item to user collection
  addToCollection(key, e) {
  const userUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  const collection = {
    marque: this.state.catalogue[key].marque,
    marquesuite: this.state.catalogue[key].marquesuite,
    numero: this.state.catalogue[key].numero,
    reference: this.state.catalogue[key].reference,
    cote: this.state.catalogue[key].cote,
    avatarURL:this.state.catalogue[key].avatarURL
  };
  firebase.database().ref(`users/${userUid}/collection`).child('items').ref.push(collection);

 }




 render(){

if(this.state.catalogue === null) {
  return  <p>Catalogue is empty</p>

}


const catalogue= Object.keys(this.state.catalogue).map(key => {
  return (

    <div className="item col-md-2" key={key}>
      <img src={this.state.catalogue[key].avatarURL} height={150} with={150}/>
      <h3>{this.state.catalogue[key].marque}</h3>
      <h3>{this.state.catalogue[key].marquesuite}</h3>
      <h4>{this.state.catalogue[key].numero}</h4>
      <h4>{this.state.catalogue[key].reference}</h4>
      <p>{this.state.catalogue[key].cote}</p>
      <div className="text-center">
      <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.addToCollection.bind(this, key)}>Add to my collection</button>
      </div>
    </div>

      )
    });
  return (
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1 class="text-center">List of item</h1>
      {catalogue}
    </div>
    )
   }
  }

  const authCondition = (authUser) => !!authUser;

  export default withAuthorization(authCondition)(Catalogue);
```

This is my "User Collection Page":

```
   class Collection extends React.Component {
   constructor (props) {
   super(props)
   this.state = {
    collection: {}
   };

   }

   //Data from Firebase Database
   componentDidMount() {
   var userUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
   const collection =firebase.database().ref(`/users/${userUid}/collection/items`).orderByChild('marque')

   collection.on('value', snapshot => {
   this.setState({
   collection: snapshot.val(),
  })
 })
}

//Remove from user collection
  removeToCollection(key, e) {
  const userUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  const item = key;
  firebase.database().ref(`users/${userUid}/collection/items/${item}`)
  .remove();
}

  renderPosts() {
  this.removeToCollection = this.removeToCollection.bind(this);
  return _.map(this.state.collection, (collection, key) => {
  return (
    <div className="item col-md-3" key={key} id={key}>
       <img src={this.state.collection[key].avatarURL} height={150} with={150}/>
     <h3>{collection.marque}</h3>
     <h3>{collection.marquesuite}</h3>
     <h4>{collection.numero}</h4>
     <h4>{collection.reference}</h4>
     <p>{collection.cote}</p>
     <div className="text-center">
     <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={(e) => {if(window.confirm('Are you sure ?')){this.removeToCollection(key, e)};}}>Remove from my collection</button>
     </div>

 </div>
 )
})
}

render(){
  if(this.state.collection === null){
  return <h2>Your collection is empty</h2>
 }
  return (
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="text-center">Your collection</h1>
    {this.renderPosts()}
  </div>
)
}

}

const authCondition = (authUser) => !!authUser;

export default withAuthorization(authCondition)(Collection);
```

Any idea ?

Thank for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database doesn't have references between properties. This means that while you as the developer or user may see that each item in a collection must correspond to an item in the catalogue, Firebase has no built-in way to enforce this relationship.

What you can do is add validation rules that ensure that items in user collection exist. Say for example that you keep the catalogue and user collections like this:

```
catalogue: {
  item1: { name: "Cookies" },
  item2: { name: "Cookies" },
  item3: { name: "Cookies" }
},
collections: {
  user1: {
    item1: true,
    item2: true
  },
  user2: {
    item2: true,
    item3: true
  }
}
```

You can use the following security rules to ensure that each `/collections/$uid/$itemId` must also exist in `/catalogue`:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "collections": {
      "$uid": {
        "$itemId": {
          ".validate": "root.child('catalogue').child($itemId).exists()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This does mean that you can only remove an item from the catalogue, once no more references to that item exist in the user collections. So with the above sample data, this write will fail (since two users have the item in their collection):

```
firebase.database().ref("catalogue").child("item2").remove()
```

But if we run the following code in sequence, it will work:

```
firebase.database().ref("collections/user1/item2").remove().then(function() {
  firebase.database().ref("collections/user2/item2").remove().then(function() {
    firebase.database().ref("catalogue").child("item2").remove()
  })
})
```

This nesting of code is rather awkward though, and the updates are not atomic. That's why you'll often see such "cascading deletes" done with a single multi-location update:

```
firebase.database().ref().update({
  "collections/user1/item2": null,
  "collections/user2/item2": null,
  "catalogue/item2": null
})
```

This single statement updates three properties in the database, and validates that the result of all three updates combined is valid according to the rules (which it is in this case).

Comment: Hello Frank van Puffelen, sorry for the response time but thank you for your advice. It's more clear for me now !